# Typescript generic function which gives component properties based on other variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This one has been puzzling me for a while, trying to create a type-safe email service.

I have an enum of possible template names:

```js
enum TemplateName {
 EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE = "EXAMPLE TEMPLATE"
 ...
}
```

I have an object of default settings per template:

```js
type EmailConfig<X = React.ComponentType> = {
 html: X
 subject: string
 ...
}

type EmailMapping: EmailConfig = {
 [key in TemplateName]: EmailConfig
}

const Emails = {
 [TemplateName.EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE]: {
    html: TestTemplate, // THIS IS A REACT FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT
    subject: "This is a test",
    ...rest
 }
 ...
}
```

My Templates look like so:

```js
export interface TestTemplateProps {
  title?: string
  firstName?: string
  preview?: string
  headline?: string
  site?: string
  ...
}

export const TestTemplate: React.FC<TestTemplateProps> = ({
  title = 'Test Email',
  site = 'My Website',
  preview = 'Important Information from My Site',
  firstName = 'there',
  headline,
  children,
}) => {
  return (
  ...
  )
}
```

I have a generic function I want to be able to pass in an enum value and all the props of the Component that relates to that enum value.

FOR EXAMPLE

```
sendEmail(TemplateName.EXAMPLE_TEMPLATE, { ... })
```

Where { ... } is typed to TestTemplateProps interface

My current attempt at `sendEmail` looks like this:

```js
async sendEmail<X extends keyof EmailMapping>(
    template: X,
    opts: React.ComponentProps<typeof Emails[X]['html']>
  ) {
...
}
```

I've tried just playing around (honestly I am just guessing at what to change at this point) and this is the closest I have come so far.

When I call sendEmail with above code, it forced me to pass one of the Enums, but then in the `opts` the only "typing" that appears is "children?" and none of the other properties in the TestTemplateProps so I think I'm close!

TIA

Comment: Your code works for me. Typescript is able to infer the props of the component corresponding to the enum

Comment: Hmmmm all I get is "children?" as the only prop, no matter what I pass in as the first enum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. but the first thing that I wanna know is ... are you making a class for data loading and passing data in your interfaces with `static function` or `static constructor` for async data loading... if so ... I want to know the
the exact problem you're facing...

Comment: Not sure I follow. I don't have any async data loading in this. My problem is I want to pass a string to a function, that string corresponds to the key of an object that has a React Component as one of its properties. I then want the function to allow me to pass the Props of that React Component and be type safe. My functions all work perfectly as is, they just aren't type safe.

Comment: alright James. Please Do make a make a class and static Function ... pass an Instance to it which have the type of class that you have made ... the make a public async function that returns a promise of preferably Interface... code it as U want to ... and the call that function Using await keyword in any function of you're React Component ... and pass an Item / String or what ever you want...